# Looking for an algorithm to switch lights in traffic light

Tags: java

Given a greenLightDuration and a yellowLightDuration, I need to switch lights (including red Light) based on duration. This all happens inside a run method for the traffic light. The reason for the run method is because it is used when running the entire simulation (trafficLight is an Agent).

```
   //Run method for agents in Model
    public void run(double duration) {
            if (disposed)
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            for (int i=0; i<duration; i++) {
                time++;
                for (Agent a : agents.toArray(new Agent[0])) {
                    a.run(time);
                }
                super.setChanged();
                super.notifyObservers();
            }
        }
```

In Light I have the run method...

```
 public void run(double runTime){   
  double check_time = runtime - time;

        if(check_time >= yellowLightDuration&& color == Color.RED){
            color = Color.GREEN;
            time = runtime;

        }else if(check_time >= greenLightDuration&& color == Color.GREEN){
            color = Color.RED;
            time = runtime;
        }
```

...but it was just something silly I did to get the lights switching from red/green and obviously does not work for yellow or is not proportionate to green/yellow light duration(I don't think).

For color I use 
`Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN` from `java.awt.Color`.

```
public void run(double runtime){
        if(this.color == Color.GREEN){
            if(time%greenLightDuration==0){
                color = Color.YELLOW;
            }
        }
        if(this.color == Color.YELLOW){
            if(time%yellowLightDuration == 0){
                color = Color.RED;
            }
        }
        else
            color = Color.GREEN;
    }
```

Tried this but the three colors are blinking furiously. I set green to 200 and yellow to 40.

Comment: Is this a GUI application or console?

Comment: Just wondering, where is `time` defined in run? Do you get it from the variable defined privately in the class, and it is changed from another class?

Comment: This is a GUI application but I have all the animation stuff done all I need is for the colors to switch based on given time (with given yellow and green light duration). I know it's trivial but I'm stuck...

Comment: I would also make the traffic light into a state machine and have the light color as it's current state, and do methods based on it's state. For example, if car pulls up send signal to traffic light, wait some seconds then change to yellow and send another signal. Wait same time then send to red light. Keep red light until another car pulls up from other side, or have the default be green for one way. (So either send a signal or keep red).

Comment: The time for the whole model is done in main with `model.run(time);`

Comment: If you want it based on time, do what I stated above except instead of a car, have it be something like ten seconds time for the signal to send at first, alternating with 10,2,2,10,2,2 etc.

Comment: Where is the `time` in the method `void run (double duration)` coming from? Is it a private variable in the class?

Comment: It is a private variable in the model class. Just a placeholder for when the argument is passed in the for loop.

Comment: I don't understand if you mean to simulate this in real-time or in some model-time? it looks like the later but then what are your units? Also, what is `time` in the traffic light's `run(double runTime)`?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a cycle, you want to get the current phase of the cycle using the modulus operator.  Something like: `double phase = (runTime - startTime) % (greenDuration + yellowDuration + redDuration)`.  You can take the modulus of a floating-point number in Java.

Comment: I tried doing something similar but my colors are blinking like christmas lights on steroids. Also, in your example, what is startTime?

Comment: @marcco_m Make sure the units of your durations are the same as the units of your clock, or convert them.

Comment: How do I know if they are? Sorry I'm bad at thinking about time in a program. They're both doubles if you mean type?

Comment: @marcco_m I mean, where do you get `runtime` and `time` from?  If you’re giving your durations in seconds, so 10.0 represents ten seconds between changes, but your clock is reporting time in milliseconds or nanoseconds, that could cause your bug.

Answer (score 0):

> the three colors are blinking furiously.

The first/main cause of this is the simulator/model, and not necessarily the traffic light (though your traffic light my still be a problem). The issue is that your current model for time is just some sketchy for-loop, which will run however fast it runs... and it clearly runs a lot faster than your eyes would like.

What you can do is attempt to control the time in your simulation, using [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) to delay the program momentarily. The following version will run an iteration roughly once per millisecond...

```
//Run method for agents in Model
public void run(double duration) {
        if (disposed)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        for (int i=0; i<duration; i++) {
            time++;
            try{ Thread.sleep(1); } //wait 1ms
            catch(Exception e){} //just resume after interruption
            for (Agent a : agents.toArray(new Agent[0])) {
                a.run(time);
            }
            super.setChanged();
            super.notifyObservers();
        }
    }
```

Now a duration of 300 for green lights takes roughly 0.3 seconds, which is brisk but not unobservable.